# How to find usages of equals and hashCode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, how do I find the usages of the `equals` and `hashCode`? For example, if I have the following code:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();

List<Person> people = List.of(p1, p2);
System.out.println(people.contains(p1));// equals usage

HashSet<Person> peopleSet = new HashSet<Person>();
peopleSet.add(p1);
peopleSet.add(p2);// hashCode usage
```

Is there a way to track down these kind of usages?

Comment: Why do you want to know private implementation details?

Comment: yes, you can track equals and hashCode but IDE will return for each and every class's equals and hashCode, because it is override method from Object class and each java class extends Object class

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to find the source code for `Person.equals (Object o)` and `Person.hashCode ()`? If so, why?

Comment: @m0skit0 @old-dog-programmer I want to change the `equals` and `hashCode` implementation of the `Person` class. But I want to track down the location in the code where these methods are used(directly and indirectly) so I can understand the impact.

Comment: Either print stack trace from equals()/hashCode() or just put a break point. And then run all unit tests. Or just click through the whole app. I don't think there's any simpler way..

Comment: The impact is you change how anyone using your `#equals` and `#hashcode` will behave. That includes pretty much any class in the collections api, and any hash tables for `#hashCode`.  If you read the javadoc for those methods, it's noted that there is a "contractual" relationship between the two methods (if `o1.equals(o2)` then `o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()`), as well as `#hashCode` being for "the benefit of hash tables". Follow the documentation to a T and there should not be a problem with the behavior of your methods in other classes.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev A few classes in the JDK also use equals/hashcode as presented by OP in his question, how are you going to account for those?

Comment: To be clear:  Do you have the code for `Person` class? Are you responsible for maintaining it?  I suspect there might be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.